# ¿Como funciona esta función en una clase?

Tags: javascript, class, diseño-de-clases

Buenas tardes estimada comunidad, espero se encuentre bien

Me encuentro aprendiendo javascript y estoy con un modulo de clases, me encontraba realizando un ejercicio de facturación el cual consiste en crear una clase de orden y una clase de productos.

Detalle: Los productos se agregan a la orden.

En uno de los requerimientos se me pide crear una función, la cual calcule el precio de los productos la cual funciona de esta manera

En la clase ORDEN, declaro el metodo precio

```
 get precio (){
        return this._precio
    }
```

y en la clase PRODUCTO, declaro el metodo calcularTotal

```
calcularTotal(){
        let totalvalor = 0;
        for (let producto of this._productos) {
            totalvalor += producto.precio
        }

        return totalvalor
    }
```

Mi duda es, ¿Por que cuando declaro la variable "producto" para que itere lo que esta en "_producto"
al momento de agregarlo al totalvalor, puedo usar un metodo de otra clase?

¿Como hace esa vinculación de entender cual es el producto y tomar el valor del producto?

NOTA: EL CODIGO FUNCIONA, pero tengo esta duda, porque quiero entender como funciona mas a profundidas este tema de las clases,metodos, funciones, etc.

GRACIAS..

El codigo no tiene problemas, solo intento entender mas como funciona javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una clase es como una caja de herramientas, con tus herramientas puedes crear un objeto, modificarlo, y obtener datos del mismo.
Por lo que puedes deducir, que el método **get precio()**, debe ser parte de la clase **Producto** (precio es un atributo de producto).
La clase **Orden**, debe tener como atributo, una lista de productos, cuando necesitas hacer una operación, por ejemplo calcular el importe total, invocas a tu objeto Orden, le pides la lista de productos, iteras sobre las misma, a cada producto le pides su precio, y lo sumas a la variable que usarás como retorno...

Comment: Muchas gracias. Ahora comprendo de donde viene y porque trae el precio en la función

Comment: Un placer ayudarte @LuisOrtiz.